# handling division by zero error in hive with below query

Tags: sql, hive

I have the following statements in hive:

```
SELECT
    cardno,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN shopcode IN (1191,1228,1225,1521) THEN amount_gbp END), 0) / COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN shopcode IN (1191,1228,1225,1521) THEN amount_gbp END), 0) AS active_cards,
    SUM(col1 + col2 + col3 + col4) / COUNT(*)
FROM
    sales
GROUP BY 
    cardno
```

I get a "division by zero" error, I cannot use nullif in hive so how can I amend the above to account for this error?

Answer (score 0):

First, more recent versions of Hive *do* support [`NULLIF()`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+udf):

```
. . . / NULLIF(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN shopcode  in (1191,1228,1225,1521) THEN amount_gbp END), 0)
```

If not, you can use a `CASE` expression:

```
. . . / (CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN shopcode  in (1191,1228,1225,1521) THEN amount_gbp END) > 0 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN shopcode  in (1191,1228,1225,1521) THEN amount_gbp END) END)
```